# Mismatch of stereoscopic rendered images on HoloLens2

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

I am using Unity 2019.3.15f1 with the MRTK 2.4.0 for developing an augmented reality app on the HoloLens 2. Unfortunately, the stereoscopic rendering is not working correctly. There is a mismatch between the images rendered for the right and the left eye. You see two images of the scene, running the app on the HoloLens. It doesn`t matter if I am using the Remote Player or ruining a builded app on the HoloLens. In both cases there are two not matching rendered images for both eyes. The HoloLens is calibrated. Other Apps from the microsoft store, or the "Homemenu" at the HoloLens have no mismatch of the images. But if I am running MRTK-example scenes on my HoloLens 2 there is also a dismatch between the rendered images for both eyes.
Does anyone had troubles with the same issue and can provide some ideas about a solution how the images can be matched correctly for both eyes?

Comment: Is there maybe a Shader in your project that doesn't support [Single-Pass Instanced](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SinglePassStereoRenderingHoloLens.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like something went wrong in your Unity project setting, it is recommended to double-check the XR Setting to troubleshoot. For XR SDK, please follow this link: [Getting started with MRTK and XR SDK](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/GettingStartedWithMRTKAndXRSDK.html). For Legacy XR, have a look at [Legacy XR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/configure-unity-project#for-legacy-xr)

Besides, we always recommend the latest Unity LTS (Long Term Support) and MRTK as the best version so that we can avoid some known issue, and the current recommendation is to use [Unity 2019.4.20f1](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/lts-releases) and [Mixed Reality Toolkit v2.5.4](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/releases/tag/v2.5.4).

Comment: Thx allot  for your advice, upgrating to Unity 2019.4.20f1 solved this problem.